# Why does this work? Shouldn't it return the smallest value?

Tags: python, loops

I have this loop that I wrote to find the smallest number in an arbutrary list:

```
arbitrary=[44,999,20,55,13,21]
smallest=None
for i in arbitrary:
 if smallest is None:
   smallest=i
 elif smallest>i:
   smallest=i
print(smallest)
```

When I run the code, it gives me the correct value. However, shouldn't it be:

```
elif smallest<i:
  smallest=i
```

When it checks to see if the next value is the smallest, it should be checking to see if i is smaller than the current i value. But running `elif smallest <i` gives me the largest value, `999`

I think I'm missing something obvious about how the loop is iterating over arbitrary, but it's just not clicking. What am I missing, and why does the original code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plain english what your elif statement is saying is that IF the smallest number in that iteration of the loop is BIGGER than the i-value then it is no longer the smallest number. This gets replaced by the i value. using a print statement in the loop can help you troubleshoot to understand what's happening.

```
arbitrary=[44,999,20,55,13,21]
smallest=None
for i in arbitrary:
 print(smallest)
 if smallest is None:
   smallest=i
 elif smallest>i:
   smallest=i
print(smallest)
```

the output of this code

```
None
44
44
20
20
13
13
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for `smallest` to be the smallest element in `arbitrary`, at the end the loop `smallest <= x` where `x` is any element in `arbitrary`.

So, as you're looping through the list, you need to update `smallest` if this condition is *not* true.

So what your code should do is the following

```
if not smallest <= x:
    smallest = x
```

Some basic algebra shows that `not smallest <= x` is the same as `smallest > x` which is faster (since it's a single operation as logical comparisons are implemented in hardware) and cleaner to write in code (fewer symbols to read).